# Loop two different CURL requets?

Tags: shell, curl, sh, git-bash

I'm setting up a shell script to process curl requests for me.

The API requires an OPTION request before I can loop all the following POST requests with my data paramerters.

Does any body know how I can improve my code and syntax in order to make the OPTIONS request happen once then loop the POST requests.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

I looked at different documentations regarding SH and browsed a lot of SO pages but no luck so far

```
#!/bin/bash
url="https://www.google.com"
    options="$(curl -s -X OPTIONS "$url"-H "Accept: */*"  -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type" -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST" -H "DNT: 1" -H "Origin: https://google.com" -H "User-Agent: Generic" -H "cache-control: no-cache")"
for options 
        do echo "$options" >> outputposts1.csv 2>&1
done
            for id in $(< idt.txt); 
                    do
                    posts="$(curl -v -s -m 5 -X POST -H "Accept: */*"  -H "Authorization: long.auth.key"  -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -H "DNT: 1"  -H "Origin: https://google.com"  -H "User-Agent: Generic"  -H "cache-control: no-cache" "$url" -d '{"profileid": "'"$id"'","content": "json content","programId": "numbers" \n')"
                    echo "$posts" >> outputposts2.csv 2>&1 
                    sleep 1s
done
```

the OPTIONS request should give a 200 status and the following POST request should give a 201 status code.

Comment: none I edited the code thanks

Comment: I think I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this myself 
basically I used shellcheck to give me pointers o syntax errors and found out that I had one in "$(curl)" the json brackets were not closed properly and found out the following syntax

```
#!/bin/bash
url="https://www.google.com"
    options="$(curl -s -X OPTIONS "$url"-H "Accept: */*")"
for options 
        do echo "$options"
done
            for id in $(< idt.txt); 
                    do
                    posts="$(curl -v -s -m 5 -X POST -H "Accept: */*" "$url" -d '{"profileid": "'"$id"'","content": "json content","programId": "numbers"}')
                    echo "$posts"
                    sleep 1s
done
```

Comment: `for options` is short for `for options in "$@"`. If you actually have any positional arguments to your script, that loop will overwrite whatever response you got from the call to `curl`.